# How to convert this filter chain class in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am in the process of converting a legacy website from SF 1.x to S2.

There is a class in the old code that taps into the SF v1 filter chain. This is a snippet of the class:

```
class myFilter extends sfFilter
{
    public function execute($filterChain)
    {
        // Execute this filter only once
        if ($this->isFirstCall())
        {
            // Filters don't have direct access to the request and user objects.
            // You will need to use the context object to get them
            $context = $this->getContext();
            $user = $context->getUser();

            if ($user->isAuthenticated())
            {                
                // Do something
            }
        }

        // Execute next filter
        $filterChain->execute();
    }

}
```

I want to be able to implement this functionality, i.e. to snoop in on requests, and take an action based on the user session. It appears that SF has done away with the filter chain, and I have looked at the documentation on the Symfony internals, but I can't find something (i.e. a small snippet like the one above), that can help me get started.

Does anyone know how I can listen in on requests (as could be done via filter chains in v1), but using the new mechanisms afforded in SF2?.

A snippet to show how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with first Symfony, but I guess you are looking for [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html). Particulary `onKernelRequest` one. All you have to do is create Listener class, register it as a service and inject whatever you need and you are good to go.

For example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = new RedirectResponse('http://www.google.com');
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

This listener would redirect everyone to google. If you need to, for example, send mails you could inject SwiftMailer to this listener's service and use it as you'd use it normally. Listeners in Symfony2 have also priorities by which you can adjust order of their execution:

> There is an additional tag option priority that is optional and
>   defaults to 0. This value can be from -255 to 255, and the listeners
>   will be executed in the order of their priority. This is useful when
>   you need to guarantee that one listener is executed before another.

There's one more solution, but it's not as elegant as using listeners. You could create base controller and put all your logic into its constructor. All other controllers would have to extend this controller (in case you want to do something on all pages).

Comment: Hi. I am aware of events. Thankfully, its one of the few things that hasn't changed much in SF2. The filter chain mechanism is lower level than events (I think). It basically allows you to listen in on requests and redirect the request if possible. This is how SF v1 implemented security (amongst other things). With events, I don't think I can redirect a request, for example

Comment: I updated the answer. As I said I didn't work with S1, so I can't say if it's the same as filters, but with listeners you can sniff almost everything in S2. The powerful thing is that via dependency injection, you can inject any other service into it and use it. I'll update the question with one more solution in few minutes.

Comment: @OndrejSlinták your response is almost correct. Rather than calling $response->send() you should set a Response on the $event: $event->setResponse($response); more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event